# Array reshape into n*n

Tags: python, arrays, reshape

I have this code where I create n * n entries and save out the inputed data, but I want to keep the shape of the matrix, for example when I create an 2*2, the matrix should look like after the save : [[1 2][3 4]]
But when I save it out it looks like: [1 2 3 4]

How can I reshape it?

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x300')
root.title('PythonExamples.org - Tkinter Example')

global e1
global numm
global my_entry
my_entry= Entry(root)
e1=Entry(root)
e1.place(x=100,y=180)
entries=[]
new_array=[]



def create():
    numm=int(e1.get())
    global my_entry
    for x in range(numm):
        for i in range(numm):
            my_entry = Entry(root)
            my_entry.grid(row=x, column=i)
            entries.append(my_entry)

def save():

    my_array = [int(entry.get()) for entry in entries]
    new_array = np.asarray(my_array)
    print(new_array)



create = Button(root,text='Submit',command=create).place(x=40,y=180)
save = Button(root,text='calc',command=save).place(x=40,y=210)

my_label=Label(root,text='')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create` function should be modified to:

```
def create():
  numm = int(e1.get())
  global my_entry
  for x in range(numm):
    row = []
    for i in range(numm):
      my_entry = Entry(root)
      my_entry.grid(row=x, column=i)
      row.append(my_entry)
    entries.append(row)
```

The `save` function should be modified to:

```
def save():
  my_array = [[int(el.get()) for el in row] for row in entries]
  new_array = np.asarray(my_array)
  print(new_array)
```

A sample output is:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already have `numpy.array` you can easily use `.reshape`

```
import numpy as np
my_array = [1,2,3,4]
new_array = np.asarray(my_array).reshape((2,2))
print(new_array)
```

output

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

Note: for demonstration purposes I use fixed value of `2`, you should use `numm` instead which should be retrieved same way as in `create` function.